# Apollo readQuery Fails Even Though Target Object is Present?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client

I'm working on a call to readQuery. I'm getting an error message:

```
modules.js?hash=2d0033b4773d9cb6f118946043f7a3d4385825fe:25847 
Error: Can't find field resolutions({"id":"Resolution:DHSzPa8bvPCDjuAac"}) 
on object (ROOT_QUERY) {
  "resolutions": [
    {
      "type": "id",
      "id": "Resolution:AepgCCio9KWGkwyMC",
      "generated": false
    },
    {
      "type": "id",
      "id": "Resolution:DHSzPa8bvPCDjuAac",  // <==ID I'M SEEKING
      "generated": false
    }
  ],
  "user": {
    "type": "id",
    "id": "User:WWv57KsvqWeAoBNHY",
    "generated": false
  }
}.
```

The object with that id appears to be plainly visible as the second entry in the list of resolutions.

Here's my query:

```
const GET_CURRENT_RESOLUTION_AND_GOALS = gql`
  query Resolutions($id: String!) {
    resolutions(id: $id) {
      _id
      name
      completed
      goals {
        _id
        name
        completed
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

...and here's how I'm calling it:

```
<Mutation
    mutation={CREATE_GOAL}
    update={(cache, {data: {createGoal}}) => {
        let id = 'Resolution:' + resolutionId;
        const {resolutions} = cache.readQuery({
            query: GET_CURRENT_RESOLUTION_AND_GOALS,
            variables: {
                id
            },
        });
    }}
>
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

Per the GraphQL Dev Tools extension for Chrome, here's the whole GraphQL data store:

```
{
  "data": {
    "resolutions": [
      {
        "_id": "AepgCCio9KWGkwyMC",
        "name": "testing 123",
        "completed": false,
        "goals": [
          {
            "_id": "TXq4nvukpLcqQhMRL",
            "name": "test goal abc",
            "completed": false,
            "__typename": "Goal"
          },
        ],
        "__typename": "Resolution"
      },
      {
        "_id": "DHSzPa8bvPCDjuAac",
        "name": "testing 345",
        "completed": false,
        "goals": [
          {
            "_id": "PEkg5oEEi2tJ6i8LH",
            "name": "goal abc",
            "completed": false,
            "__typename": "Goal"
          },
          {
            "_id": "X4H4dFzGm5gkq5bPE",
            "name": "goal bcd",
            "completed": false,
            "__typename": "Goal"
          },
          {
            "_id": "hYunrXsMq7Gme7Xck",
            "name": "goal cde",
            "completed": false,
            "__typename": "Goal"
          }
        "__typename": "Resolution"
      }
    ],
    "user": {
      "_id": "WWv57KsvqWeAoBNHY",
      "__typename": "User"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without `Resolution:` as this seems to the prefix apollo adds to every id. Use the same `id` as when you make the query.

Comment: Yes, I tried it both ways, with and without adding "Resolution:" to the id.

Comment: What is the __typename of your resolution object ? Maybe use readFragment instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#readfragment

Comment: The typename of the object I am seeking via readQuery is "Resolution". Should I not be able to find it via readQuery alone?

Comment: I just updated the original post with a snapshot of the entire GraphQL data store, via the GraphQL dev tools for Chrome. Does this provide the additional info needed regarding why my call to readQuery isn't yet working?

Comment: First, prefixing the id with 'Resolution' seems wrong to me. Then the question arises how is your datastore filled? To read a query from cache, the query needs to have been called with exactly the same arguments on the remote API before. To circumvent that and resolve the query locally you can implement a cache resolver. Have a look at the example in the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html#cacheRedirect)

Comment: @Herku, thanks very much. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted as answer for fellow apollo users with similar problems:

Remove the prefix of `Resolution:`, the query should only take the id.

Then the question arises how is your datastore filled?
To read a query from cache, the query needs to have been called with exactly the same arguments on the remote API before. This way apollo knows what the result for a field is with specific arguments. If you never called the remote endpoint with the arguments you want to use but know what the result would be, you can circumvent that and resolve the query locally by implementing a cache resolver. Have a look at the example in the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html#cacheRedirect). Here the store contains a list of books (in your case `resultions`) and the query for a single book by id can be resolved with a simple cache lookup.