# GraphQL/Apollo Client: get data from cache if a query is a subset of a previous query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm new to GraphQL and I thought it would do this automatically.

E.g. if I fetch a list of posts, then open an individual post, the data for that post is already in memory. I expected GraphQL to be able to re-use the data from cache, but it makes another network request.

The schema is something like:

```
  type Query {
    posts: [Post]
    post(id: ID): Post
  }
```

I'm using React. In `PostsRoute`, I have:

```
  useQuery(gql`
    query {
      posts {
        id
        title
      }
    }
  `);
```

In `PostRoute`, I have:

```
  useQuery(gql`
    query {
      post(id: ${postId}) {
        id
        title
      }
    }
  `);
```

Is there something I need to configure for Apollo to use the cached data automatically? Or is this something that Apollo doesn't support by default?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apollo client cache doesn't work as I excpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959745/apollo-client-cache-doesnt-work-as-i-excpected)

Answer (score 0):

**Apollo 2**

If you are using Apollo 2, what you're looking for is probably [cacheRedirects](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/performance/performance/#redirecting-to-cached-data). It is used to intercept a query and resolve it using the cache. The linked document actually explains exactly your use-case so I recommend you look at it, but for posterity, here's how I do it personally (adapted to your situation).

In your `InMemoryCache` options when you instantiate it, add a `cacheRedirects` field and specify a custom resolver for your `post` query, like so:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      post: (_, {id}, {getCacheKey}) => getCacheKey({__typename: "Post", id}),
    },
  },
});
```

This assumes that the `__typename` of your post is `Post`. First argument of the custom resolver is the result of the `ROOT_QUERY`, which we don't use here. Second argument is the arguments that are passed to the query (`{id: "some_id"}` here) and the third one is the context, containing `client`, `cache` and `getCacheKey`. Only `getCacheKey` is useful to us here. That method take a `__typename` and an `id`, and returns its key in the cache.

This completes the custom resolver. Now when you query `post(id: some_id)` it will look at the custom resolver, receive the cache key and return the result from the cache matching that key.

**Apollo 3**

`cacheRedirects` has been removed in Apollo 3, but the same functionality can be achieved with [field policies](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects-using-field-policy-read-functions). You still need to set it up when instantiating `InMemoryCache`, but it's slightly different:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        post: (_, {args, toReference}) => toReference({__typename: "Post", id: args.id}),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

We define a field policy read on the field `post` on type `Query`. Note that the second argument now includes both `args` and the helper utilities. This includes `toReference`, that's basically the new `getCacheKey`.