# how can I use partial data with relay?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, graphql, relayjs

I recently start to learn relay and have a question about how I can use partial data with relay.

```
// Screen A
const ProductsPageQuery = graphql`
    query products_PageQuery {
        products(first: 5, channel: "default-channel") {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    name
                    description
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;

const Page = ({ preloadedQuery }: RelayProps<{}, products_PageQuery>) => {
    const { products } = usePreloadedQuery(ProductsPageQuery, preloadedQuery);

    return (
        <div>
            <code>products page</code>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(products, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
    );
};

// Screen B
const MenusPageQuery = graphql`
    query menus_PageQuery {
        products(first: 5, channel: "default-channel") {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    name
                    description
                }
            }
        }
        menus(first: 5) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    name
                    slug
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;

const Page = ({ preloadedQuery }: RelayProps<{}, menus_PageQuery>) => {
    const { products, menus } = usePreloadedQuery(MenusPageQuery, preloadedQuery);

    return (
        <div>
            <code>menues page</code>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(products, null, 2)}</pre>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(menus, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
    );
};
```

when I navigate to screen A to B relay makes server call and global suspense activates.
I'm sure relay knows about the cached `products`. because when I navigate screen B to A or set { fetchPolicy:'store-only' } to Screen B, I get the cached `products` data with no loading or server call.
but with additional `menus` field, it seems relay makes query from scratch.
so is there a way to use partially cached query data with relay? such as like display cached parts and show loader while the rest is still pending? am I expecting some kind of defer mechanism that should implemented on react level not relay?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using apollo client 3, you can utilise `InMemoryCache`.

[Here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects) is the detailed document for the same.

Apollo client is going to take each query as separate call, so basically you need to tell it that products data can be taken from cached data.

You can also find more information for the same from another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/65112751/3134215

Comment: it is relay and it's bit different than the situation that the exact cache pointing the same entity or node is there but you need to teach client's resolvers to how to find it